# When to use the save: method of NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

The question is quite simple: when should I use the `save:(NSError **)error` method of NSManagedObjectContext? From what I understand the only thing it does it save changed data to the persistent store. The Xcode template-generated application delegate calls the save: method on `applicationWillTerminate`, is that sufficient?

Details about my code:

- Multi-threaded (doing operations in the background, thus using multiple `NSManagedObjectContext`'s)
- I'm using a single `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`
- Data changed on background threads is merged using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`
- If you need to know more, please do ask!

I couldn't find a guideline on when to call it, so I decided to ask you all. Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always need to call save: when you want your data to save.  You can't always guarantee that applicationWillTerminate will be called.  For example, if your application crashes due to  memory issues (or due to one of a handful of other things) then this won't be called.

I would save data when the user completes the action that is actually generating the data to save.

Comment: And for background tasks like fetching new information from the web and adding that into the model you'd save it when you are done adding? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes - I'd save when it was done.  Remember, your ManagedObjectContext is thread-specific, so don't ever create a background thread to do your saving for you.

Comment: I do call `save:` on the same thread I create the NSManagedObjectContext, which most of the time happens to be on background threads. That shouldn't be a problem, as long as initiating and saving happens on the same thread, right :-)

Comment: You should be fine, but if issues do crop up, then remember this could be a potential problem spot.